# #autoit Reading 'constantly changing' string

Tags: string, internet-explorer, text, autoit

Let's say there is some numbers/characters thats constantly changing.

And my goal is to read those values under 'inactive window':

```
#include <IE.au3>
Global $fb1 = _IECreate(https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=oPLYV6qlMMbM8ge3xqiYDg#q=tennis+racquet+price)
```

[image: sample screen]

That tennis racquet prices would likely to change and I want to get the values.

My stupid plan was to:

1. get the position of `$` and read the text to the right (if possible)
2. find the row number and read that whole string to extract values
3. catch the string from `$` to `sport chek`, and proceed (if possible)

All of them failed under `inactive window`! I read thru all the `_IE` functions and regular functions.

Could you please give me some hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's best to use an Invisible IE window. You can use an inactive one and just minimize it but why go through that trouble.

The Below code will read the results using a hidden IE window so it can't take focus. It looks at the HTML classes and grabs the name and prices and displays them in a message box. Since the name is incomplete, your unique identifier might be the link under the div class="pla-unit-title"

```
#include <IE.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <StringConstants.au3>
Global $fb1 = _IECreate("https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=oPLYV6qlMMbM8ge3xqiYDg#q=tennis+racquet+price",0,0)
sleep(2000);wait for all data to load
$fullHtml = _IEDocReadHTML ($fb1)

$racketNames = StringRegExp($fullHtml,"(?s)(?U)<div class=""pla-unit-title.*>(.*)</div>",3)
$racketPrices = StringRegExp($fullHtml,"(?s)(?U)<div class=""_QD.*>(.*)</div>",3)

_IEQuit($fb1);
For $i = 0 To UBound($racketPrices) - 1
   $racketName = getTextBetweenTags($racketNames[$i])
   $racketPrice = getTextBetweenTags($racketPrices[$i])
    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Racket:" & $i,$racketName & " priced at " &  $racketPrice)
Next
func getTextBetweenTags($html)
    $value = StringTrimLeft($html,StringInStr($html,">"))
    $value = StringLeft($value,StringInStr($value,"<")-1)
    return $value;
EndFunc
```